# Updating a number column with a new string of numbers starting at particular number

Tags: sql, oracle

So, I have a table ITEMS.
It has columns NAME, DATE, and NUMBER.
Currently, Number column looks something like this:

```
NUMBER
300000  
300001  
300002
```

It has about 750 entries. I'd like to update the Number column with sequential numbers starting at 400045, increasing by 1.

Additionally, there are a few items there already with the number 400000 (i.e. between 400000 and 400045) so I wouldn't want to update those.

I've tried stuff such as:

```
DECLARE @id INT   
SET @id = 400000   
UPDATE **ITEMS**  
SET @id = **NUMBER** = @id + 1
```

Comment: Which database do you really use? Code you posted isn't Oracle.

Comment: Have you considered a PL/SQL `FOR` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess below query is generic enough to work for you -

```
UPDATE ITEMS
SET NUMBER = (SELECT rn 
              FROM (SELECT NUMBER, 
                           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NUMBER) + 400045 rn
                    FROM ITEMS
                    WHERE NUMBER NOT BETWEEN 400000 AND 400045) X
              WHERE X.NUMBER = ITEMS.NUMBER)
```

Though you should not keep column name as number as this might be confusing for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get the following error:

SQL Error: ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here

Comment: Please specify your DB product. You have tagged Oracle but code seems to be of SQL SERVER.

Comment: Ankit, my apologies, you are completely right, it is SQL. I'm really sorry, this isn't my expertise. I appreciate your help!

Comment: @MilosBogetic, Please tag your version also. It helps a lot for the resolution.

Comment: Tagged properly. Thanks.

Comment: You forgot the Sql Server Version though.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
"CORE 11.2.0.4.0 Production"
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

Comment: @MilosBogetic, This is Oracle version not SQL Server.

Comment: I'm honestly lost here. This is the SQL for the table I;m working in:

CREATE TABLE "ITEMS"."ITEMS_COPY" 
   ( "MENU_ITEM_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
 "SHORT_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
 "MENU_NAME" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,

Comment: I have updated the answer based on SQL Server. I am still not sure if you are using SQL Server or Oracle. If you don't know that, Better if you can just post an image of your tool. We will try to guess.

Comment: Thanks again, now I get this:

Error at Command Line : 3 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Happy to post any screenshots if you tell me exactly whats needed. Much appreciated.

Comment: Too much confusion. The code you posted is of SQL Server. Error you get is from Oracle. You are not sure which DBMS you are using. Hmmm, Please post the image of your DB product. BTW, I have again updated my answer based on Oracle.

Comment: Added a screenshot to main post. This is the recent error:

rror report -
SQL Error: ORA-01407: cannot update ("ITEMS"."ITEMS"."NUMBER") to NULL
01407. 00000 -  "cannot update (%s) to NULL"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @MilosBogetic, Please try now.

Comment: That did it! Just had to make the column nullable to work it. Thank you so much, this is very kind of you.

Comment: Not sure why you have made that column nullable but glad to know that I was able to help you.

Comment: I was getting an error saying the changes cannot be made as the column is not nullable.

Comment: But we are not setting anything to null. You can just run the select statement andsee if there is any null coming in the result set.